# What is the outcome of joining the Disciples of the Changing God

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

If I join the Disciples of the Changing God, will that result in an outcome that can't be reversed?

Is there a way to join without bad outcomes or consequences?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to complete this quest.

- Do the quest The Sorrow's Pray from Zaofi the sculptor. During this quest you can learn about a castoff and reveal their identity to the cult. This has no negative consequences in any form.
- The other option involves the Beloved slave quest. You can learn about another castoff, but revealing their identity to the cult causes the NPC to leave the city.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. But what about consequences storywise of joining the cult?